# Codeigniter large form insertion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've a form with 120 fields to insert into the DB. The form is inserting fine and the approach I used is below:
I'm fetching all the fields from the view as below in the controller and passing the array($postdata) to the model file to insert.

```
**View**
$postdata = array(
'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'), //1st field
'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'), // 2nd field
'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
....
....
'test' => $this->input->post('test') // 120th field.
);
$this->Form_Model->insertdata($postdata);

**Model:**
function insertdata($data = array()) {
        $sql_query = $this->db->insert('form_insert', $data);
        redirect('Form');
}
```

My question is Is there any better way to insert. This approach feels bit repetitive.

Comment: Not sure a table with 120 fields is a good idea.  Perhaps look at the design and see if some of these fields logically belong in their own table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to get an array of all the data submitted, you can do it like this:

```
$postdata = $this->input->post();
```

This means, all the data submitted from the form will be there in this array. 
And if you want to remove any particular element from this array, you can use `unset()`.

Say for example, you may have named your submit button as "submit_btn" like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" />
```

then this value would be there in the above returned array. You can remove it like this:

```
$postdata = $this->input->post();

unset( $postdata['submit_btn']);
```

Btw, I have a couple of suggestions. The logic part is done in a `Controller`(you referred it by mistake as `View`). A `View` is simply for the displaying. And the `Model` is for the database communication.

Also, it would always be better to do some validations on the input that you received from the User through form submissions. We may don't even know what data they are sending!

And move that `redirect()` you used in the `Model` to the `Controller` from where you were trying to call that `insertdata()` method. In that `Model`, you just return a value (true or false or maybe something else) and do the business logic inside the `Controller`

You were kind of mixing up everything. That's why I thought to give you some pointers to help you.

Hope it helps :)